# WPF Prism: Can you load modules as needed on the fly?

Tags: wpf, module, prism

I know that with Prismv4 / MEF you can load modules without including them in your bootstrapper, but could I load modules on the fly as needed? That is, I have a menu of forms:

- Form 1 (Located in Form1.dll)
- Form 2 (Located in Form2.dll)
- Form 3 (Located in Form3.dll)

Then, only when someone clicks Form 1 does it load the Form1.dll as a module, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...[load modules on demand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458932.aspx).

You essentially need a reference to the `IModuleManager`. With this you can call...

```
IModuleManager manager = //get this via DI within a constructor perhaps...
manager.LoadModule("ModuleName");
```

Comment: A bit more information would help here ;) See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer

Comment: @ChrisF I added the two lines of code prior to your comment...it is that simple...not sure what else to add other then fluff...